# Declare int variable aux a.length = (); Or use o.length () in all loops?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wonder which is faster: Say I'm working with some text (30 characters), which would be better? And with a lot of text which would be better?

1-

```
int tam = text.length();
for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    //something here//
}
```

2-

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
{
    //something here//
}
```

and also comparing these two:

1-

```
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        {
            aux = a.find(b[i]);
            if (aux == -1)
            {
                sucess = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                a.erase(aux,1);
            }
        }
```

2-

```
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        {
            if (a.find(b[i]) == -1)
            {
                sucess = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                a.erase(a.find(b[i]),1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: If it matters, measure it. But it doesn't matter here, unless your something is utterly trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both first are the better approach.

On the first example you are checking if `i<a.length()` is true on every cycle. That means that you are going to execute `a.length()` for every iteration. If the variable `a` is not changed, it is unnecessary and the better approach is to calculate before and use that value.

Note that if the variable `a` is changed inside, placing `i<a.length()` might be the correct approach. It depends on your problem.

On the second example it is the same basics. You avoid useless calculations because you won't need to calculate `a.find(b[i])` again inside the else.

Comment: Ok! Muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, as computations get bigger, more complex, and more frequent you want to minimize your unnecessary calculations. This means that storing something that needs to be calculated in a variable may speed up the process.

In both of your examples, for *extremely* large numbers,

```
int scratch = big.length();

for(int i=0;i<scratch;i++){
    //body//
}
```

is usually faster.

In the future, general questions like this tend to belong in something like the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Obrigado, realmente é melhor evitar cálculos!